# How to put '<' character in java properties file

Tags: java, properties-file

Hi I am trying to put < sign in java properties file, so that it will show message to user as ' <  symbol is not accepted ' but I am not able to put it in the file.

I tried `/</`,  `\<\`,  and  `\\<...` but it did not work.

Comment: Can you show us the entire line in question from your properties file?

Comment: Key=id should not contain <

Comment: Define 'not able to put it in the file' and 'did not work'. There is no reason why `<` on its own should not work. Impossible to imagine how you came up with any of those bizarre escape sequences, none of which is documented in the Javadoc.

Answer (score 4):

The [`Properties`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) text format has no problem with either `<`s or `>`s. The exact specification of the file format is laid out in [`Properties.load()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load-java.io.Reader-) and makes no mention of either character. This is also very easy to verify:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  Properties prop = new Properties();
  prop.put("<key>", "<value>");
  System.out.println("Properties Contents: " + prop);

  StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
  prop.store(writer, "<comment>");
  System.out.println("\nProperties File Format:\n" + writer);

  prop = new Properties();
  prop.load(new StringReader(writer.toString()));
  System.out.println("Properties Contents: " + prop);
}
```

First we construct a `Properties` object and add a `<key>`:`<value>` pair. Then we write the object to a `Writer` and print the serialized contents, then we load those contents back into a new `Properties` object and can see there was no data loss. This program outputs:

```
Properties Contents: {<key>=<value>}

Properties File Format:
#<comment>
#Sat Jul 23 23:50:50 EDT 2016
<key>=<value>

Properties Contents: {<key>=<value>}
```

You should be able to load a properties file with such symbols without issue.

---

If you're using the XML file format (via [`loadFromXML()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#loadFromXML-java.io.InputStream-) and [`storeToXML()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#storeToXML-java.io.OutputStream-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)) you need to [escape `<` and `>`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Escaping) just like you would in any XML document. If you are trying to read/write XML it would have been *very helpful* to mention that in your question.